# Swift: how to manage multiple draggable uiimageviews with touchesBegan/Moved

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uiimageview, drag

I just have created two moving/draggable `UIImageView` which are supposed to move on a larger `UIImageView` below, like the following screenshot:

[image]

And this is my code:

```
class PhotoViewController: UIViewController, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate {


@IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var redA: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var redB: UIImageView!

var imagePicker: UIImagePickerController!
var redLocationA:CGPoint = CGPoint(x:0, y:0)
var redLocationB:CGPoint = CGPoint(x:0, y:0)

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.redA.center = CGPointMake(80, 330)
    self.redB.center = CGPointMake(80, 360)
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}


override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    self.redLocationA = (touches.first?.locationInView(self.view))!
    self.redA.center = redLocationA

    self.redLocationB = (touches.first?.locationInView(self.view))!
    self.redB.center = redLocationB
}

override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

    self.redLocationA = (touches.first?.locationInView(self.view))!

    if ((redLocationA.x >= 26 && redLocationA.x <= 292) && (redLocationA.y >= 71 && redLocationA.y <= 461)){
        redA.center = redLocationA
    }

    if ((redLocationB.x >= 26 && redLocationB.x <= 292) && (redLocationB.y >= 71 && redLocationB.y <= 461)){
        redB.center = redLocationB
    }

    print("redA: \(redLocationA)")
    print("redB: \(redLocationB)")
}

...
}
```

As you can imagine when I tap on a pin then also the other is moved into the position of the first and this, I think, because I always perform the same extraction from `touches: Set<UITouch>`.
What is the correct way to manage both pin without the position of the first is overwritten on the position of the second at each tapping?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to press and drag an imageView around you should add a `panGestureRecognizer` to each imageView

Comment: Hmm... I had followed a tutorial on youtube thanks to which I wrote my code, I thought it was the right way. I have no idea of panGestureRecognizer...if you can link me a good tutorial, I would appreciate it

Comment: I don't know what kind of tutorial you do well with but if you google UIPanGestureRecognizer or even UIGestureRecognizer they aren't too complicated.

Here's the documentation if that helps:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPanGestureRecognizer_Class/